# c++ writing to a file

Tags: c++

I want to write data to a file in a directory i.e.

```
path_file = "/Users/aajd/2010M9/2010M9.txt";
std::ofstream outFile(path_file);
```

The name of the file and the path to the file is dependent of the outcome of the program.
How can i accomplish this?
Is it necessary that the directory already exists?

Thanks,
André

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the folder must exist if you want to open/create a file in it.

Check this [Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) on output through iostream

and the [c++ reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/start)

and the [MSDN entries concerning directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363950.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is necessary for the directory to exist to create the file. You have to use system calls, such as `mkdir` prior to creating the `ofstream` object.